# How can I display images with the same height with CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a dating website and I display lists of users with profile pictures. If the user doesn't have a profile picture, I display a specific image. Here is the code:

```
@register.inclusion_tag(filename='accounts/profile_picture.html', takes_context=True)
def profile_picture(context, user, geometry, with_link=True, html_class=''):
    context = copy.copy(context)
    geometry_splitted = geometry.split('x')
    width = geometry_splitted[0]
    if (len(geometry_splitted) == 2):
        height = geometry_splitted[1]
    else:
        height = geometry_splitted[0]
    context.update({
        'user': user,
        'geometry': geometry,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'with_link': with_link,
        'html_class': html_class,
    })
    return context
```

profile_picture.html:

```
{% thumbnail user.photo.file geometry crop='center 20%' as image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ user.name }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" class="img-fluid {{ html_class }}" />
{% empty %}
    <img src="{% static 'speedy-core/images/user.svg' %}" alt="" width="{{ width }}" height="{{ height }}" class="img-fluid {{ html_class }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

CSS:

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But the problem is, because of this `height: auto;` thing, users without a profile picture have profile pictures higher than users with profile pictures. I want to display all users with the same height, and if necessary, display a smaller width for users without a profile picture (which displays [`speedy-core/images/user.svg`](https://en.speedymatch.com/static/speedy-core/images/user.svg) as their profile picture). If possible, without changing the file `user.svg` itself. How do I do it with CSS?

**Edit:** I thought of defining `max-height` to these images, but I don't know the exact value for `max-height` to define for the height of the images to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I included an **Additional context** section below. For first-time readers, I suggest reading that first.

## Solution

- We create a `placeholder-wrapper` with the same `aspect_ratio` as `geometry`.
  This allows us to restrict to the same `height` (recap: the `width` is restricted by the columns).
- We center the image in the `placeholder-wrapper`.

profile_picture.html:

```html
<!-- <img src="{% static 'speedy-core/images/user.svg' %}" alt="" width="{{ width }}" height="{{ height }}" class="img-fluid {{ html_class }}" /> -->
     <div class="placeholder-wrapper" style="padding-top: {{ aspect_ratio }}%;">
         <img src="{% static 'speedy-core/images/user.svg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid {{ html_class }}" />
     </div>
```

user_tags.py:

```py
def profile_picture(...):
    ...
    context.update({
        ...
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'aspect_ratio': float(height) / float(width) * 100,  # Add this
        ...
    })
    return context
```

CSS / speedy-core.css:

```css
.profile-picture .placeholder-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.profile-picture .placeholder-wrapper > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

## Additional context

- Profile pictures are used in `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-0">`.

  - The screenshots below show 4 columns as per `col-md-3` but the solution is responsive.
  - The `width` is restricted by the columns; `height: auto`  from Bootstrap's `img-fluid`.
- There are intrinsic 2 sizes (assumption: width ≥ height).

  - Fixed-`geometry` (e.g. 256x200) `thumbnail` of free-size `user.photo.file`
  - Placeholder image (32x32) `user.svg`

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `height:auto` mention a specific height like `height:500px` , it will make all the pictures of same size.And you can use **media** queries to mention height in different screen sizes.

Comment: The problem is that the picture's width is dynamic in different screen sizes (because of `max-width: 100%;`) and therefore we need the `height: auto;` thing to make the height proportional to the width.

Comment: @Uri if that is the case then you can use **aspect ratio** feature. For more details check this page : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp